# How to start another application with a specific string in its name

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to start another application from mine in the following order:

1. Check all installed applications on device and find the applications that has a specific string on their name and list them so they can be selected and launched(eg checks for all the application which contain "timer" in their name such as "perfect timer","your timer", etc.)

2.if no application is available, start Google Play and search for the name(eg "timer").

Comment: You could probably achieve this with an `Intent`

Comment: filter selectors might be useful but i dont know how.

Comment: This funtionallity is already avaiable in framework. By using a specific intent: the application will be launched if present or user will be redirected to playstorr. For grouping similar applications use intent filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use `PackageManager` for getting all installed Applications name and use `getLaunchIntentForPackage` for launching application if it contain specific string :

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  List<ApplicationInfo> packages = 
                  pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

  for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
   if(packageInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().
                   contains(""perfect timer".toLowerCase())){

     Intent intent = 
                pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);   
      if (intent != null)  {
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
         startActivity(intent);  
      }  
  } else{
            // Launch google play app here
            String apppackname = "com.example.appname";
             Intent intentapp=new (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("market://search?q="+apppackname)));
             startActivity(intentapp);
      }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to read all the installed app read more here http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon,

after you found the desire application, you can simple fire intent to that application or else open the market with filter search like this

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=com.amazon.kindle"));
   startActivity(i);
```